# Update query not effecting all rows in database

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have the following query....

```
UPDATE vehicle_catalog SET parent_id = 0 WHERE parent_id = SUBSTR(id, 0, 5)
```

I need to set all `parent_id`s to 0 where the first 5 characters of id is the same as the parent_id.  This is effecting 0 rows when I'm looking at the data and it should be effecting over 10,000.

Any ideas on why this wouldn't be effecting all rows?

**UPDATE**
What I don't understand if I did
`UPDATE SET col = '1'` it would effect the whole database, yet my query isn't run on the whole database.

**UPDATE**
The proper solution:

```
UPDATE `vehicle_catalog` SET parent = 0 WHERE SUBSTRING(id FROM 1 FOR 6) == SUBSTRING(parent_id FROM 1 FOR 6)
```

Comment: Can you try running SELECT * FROM vehicle_catalog WHERE parent_id = SUBSTR(id, 0, 5)?  That will return the rows your query will affect.  If the SELECT is not returning any rows you need to update your condition; if it returns what you expect then something else is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SUBSTR() in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) uses 1-based indexing.  Try this:

```
UPDATE vehicle_catalog SET parent_id = 0 WHERE parent_id = SUBSTR(id, 1, 5)
```

Also, see my comment on using a SELECT query to verify that your condition is correctly constructed.

Answer (score 0):

just a guess, but

`WHERE parent_id = SUBSTR(id, 0, 5)`,    or, should it be...

```
WHERE SUBSTR(parent_id, 0, 5) = SUBSTR(id, 0, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

your update will only affect a single row as written. for instance, if the ID was 12345678, your query would only update row 12345. You might try this

```
UPDATE vehicle_catalog SET parent_id = 0 
WHERE parent_id like concat(SUBSTR(id, 0, 5), "%");
```

Comment: That doesn't work either, that replaced all of the values with 0